# Getting assembly error in search contacts and interactions

Tags: xconnect

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1

**I am getting error in below code:**

```
//Total contacts
                var results0 = client.Contacts.ToEnumerable().Count();

                //Contacts with interactions
                // Use InteractionsCache instead of client.Contacts.Where(x => x.Interactions.Any()) as not all search providers support joins
                var results = client.Contacts.Where(c => c.InteractionsCache().InteractionCaches.Any()).GetBatchEnumerator();
                var count = results.TotalCount;
```

**Error:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Sitecore.XConnect' with identity 'Sitecore.XConnect, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Interactive.Async' with identity 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'  Feature.MCX C:\projects\mcx28012021\src\Sitecore\Feature\MCX\code\CSC   1   Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are referenced wrong dlls.

I have a clean version of Sitecore 9.1.1 and it is using Sitecore.XConnect 2.0.1 and not Sitecore.XConnect 2.0.0

[image]

The System.Interactive.Async used is 3.1.1 and not 3.0.0

[image]